# Create subfolder under staticresources

Tags: lightning-web-components, static-resources, visualstudiocode

In a Lightning Experience project, I inside `force-app/main/default/` there is a `staticresources` folder. I have both CSS and JS files in there and I'm using them in LWCs using `lightning/platformResourceLoader/loadStyle` and it works just fine.

I want to organize some CSS files under a particular subfolder under `staticresources`; let's call it `mySubfolder`. For example, let's say I have a `myCss.css` file in this subfolder - the full path would be `force-app/main/default/staticresources/mySubfolder/myCss.css`.

But in Visual Studio Code I'm having trouble with this. If I create a subfolder and right click and do a `SFDX: Deploy Source to Org`, I get an error `"Component conversion failed: Cannot read property 'contentType' of undefined"`. If I try to create a file underneath that subfolder, I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a folder as a static resource; it will be converted to a .ZIP (Compressed Folder) file when you deploy it. To make this work, you need to include a metadata file that describes the resource.

Given the folder name `mySubfolder` in `staticresources`, you need a file called `mySubfolder.resource-meta.xml` in `staticresources` that contains the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StaticResource xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <cacheControl>Public</cacheControl>
    <contentType>application/x-zip-compressed</contentType>
</StaticResource>
```

*(Cache Control can be `Private` if you don't need it outside your org, e.g. Communities).*

Therefore, your files would look like:

```
+ force-app
  + main
    + default
      + staticresources
        + mySubfolder
          + myCss.css
        + mySubfolder.resource-meta.xml
```

Your LWC will reference the file such as:

```
import MYSUBFOLDER from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/mySubfolder';
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
```

...

```
Promise.all([
  loadScript(this, MYSUBFOLDER + '/myJs.js'),
  loadStyle(this, MYSUBFOLDER + '/myCss.css')
]).then(() => {
  // do stuff here
}).catch(e => {
  // report error(s)
});
```